# Show all functions that throw exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, try-catch

I am working on a Java program and I was wondering if there was some tool in Eclipse that would point out all of the methods that throw exceptions. I just want to make sure that I got all of them.

Thanks for the help,

Dan

Comment: Look for compiler error. Whenever you miss these things, Compiler will help you.

Comment: The usual "find usages" tool might help you. That said, this is what checked exceptions are for in Java.

Answer (score 1):

**Checked exception** must be caught so Eclipse will tell you about them. On the other hand **unchecked exception** (aka [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)) are "not supposed to happen", it's most of the time a programming problem. Hence Java doesn't require to catch them and AFAIK Eclipse will not display any hints to tell you about a potential issue (it's probably better for visibility).

You can read [**Unchecked Exceptions — The Controversy**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), an article where Oracle gives its state of mind about **unchecked exceptions**.

If you want to build something yourself, look the `Direct Known Subclasses` of [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), it will help you to identify exceptions that can be thrown without being caught.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I know that it should not happen, was just trying to make sure that in the case that it did, I handled them. Looks like I will need to make sure that I check every method I use! Thanks!

Comment: @dannyn382 You're welcome. Now the question is : is it better to spend time to handle every exceptions or is it better to spend time to ensure your method will not throws those exceptions? :)

Comment: Definately agree with you. It really is better to spend the time to make sure that I am not throwing exceptions. I guess I am just thinking of it as more of a "If I ever had to for whatever reason do this, how would you?" Seeing I am just learning. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First, search for the keywords. The 'throw' keyword will be in code that is detecting an error condition or can't handle some exception, while 'throws' will be methods declaring they pass on certain exceptions.

Eclipse may not be able to find all methods that throw exceptions because runtime exceptions do not need to be declared in 'throws' clauses, and may be thrown by a library call in which case you wan't find a 'throw' either.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this? 
Lets say: String s = "1"
int i = Integer.parseInt(s); 
How would I find that it throws? I just want to make sure that all the methods that I am using get the exceptions caught if they throw, and I do not know all of the methods that throw.

Answer (score 0):

If you forget to catch a *checked* exception (extends `Exception`), the code will not compile. If you forget to catch a *unchecked* exception (extends `RuntimeException`), that's normally the better way. [Read Up](http://codeisland.org/2012/catching-practice/)

Answer (score 0):

If your program catches Exception in the main method (initial execution context) you will be informed if some exception was throwed but not handled.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
       // .... anything you want to do
    } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace(); // useful to visualize the stack trace and ping point others places to catch exceptions
    } catch(Throwable t) {
       // if you want to check for errors also, but generally there isn't much to do in this case
    }
}
```

A side note, since Java implements the concept of checked (Exception) and unchecked RuntimeException) exceptions, is mandatory to deal with checked, and this informs the exceptions that a correct program should try/catch/finally. But unchecked informs situations normally indicating a bug, and good practices and defensive programming should avoid, so you don't have to deal with it.