# Eclipse, highlight all methods that throw exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

is there a way to tell eclipse to highlight every method in a code block that can throw an exception?
I know that Eclipse highlights all methods that throws a given Exception in a try-block when hovering over `catch(SomeException e)` , but thats not what I want..

regards

Comment: If you have `catch (Exception e)` or `throws Exception` then it will highlight all kinds of exception.

Comment: yes, but I want Eclipse to highlight 'throwers' in all any kind of code blocks (without 'catch' or 'throws')

Answer (score 0):

Check out answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706944/eclipse-find-lines-in-a-block-that-can-throw-exceptions) question or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822678/show-all-functions-that-throw-exceptions) question. But it looks like there are only workarounds, like delete catch block and see which lines are underlined.